# How can I connect IKDeviceBrowserView with IKScannerDeviceView?

Tags: ikimagekit

I am trying to build a MacOS Objective C app using XCode 12.3 on McOS 10.15 to obtain an image from a scanner. I followed the instructions provided by Apple in 2008  in https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.363.9131&rep=rep1&type=pdf  and dragged ImageKitDeviceBrowserView and ImageKitScannerDeviceView from the Object Library onto a window. However, connecting them by control-dragging from BrowserView onto device view only moves the BrowserView. No connection is established.
Ctrl-dragging only sets up constraints between the two objects.
In an example application (GIMP Scanner plugin) the ScannerDevice view has as its delegate Outlet Scanner Device View and the BrowserView has a Referencing Outlet of delegate connected to Device Browser view, but I cannot seem to make this connection.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Found that if I drag ImageKitDeviceBrowserView and ImageKitScannerDevice outside the desired window, I can ctrl-drag from BrowserView to ScannerDevice and create the required connection. I could then cut and paste the two objects into my window.